# Doesn't show me absolute path when I use webflux and hateoas

Tags: java, spring-webflux, spring-hateoas

I'm reading *spring in action 5th* and learning spring-cloud, hateoas and webflux.I tried to write a rest controller as following

```
import static org.springframework.hateoas.server.reactive.WebFluxLinkBuilder.*;

@RestController
@RequestMapping(path = "/")
public class ServiceController {  
    
    private IngredientServiceClient ingredientClient;

    @Autowired
    public ServiceController(IngredientServiceClient ingredientClient) {
        this.ingredientClient = ingredientClient;
    }

    @GetMapping("/ingredients/{id}")
    public Mono<EntityModel<Ingredient>> getIngredientById(@PathVariable("id") String id) {
        return ingredientClient.getIngredientById(id)
            .flatMap(ingredient -> {
                EntityModel<Ingredient> model = EntityModel.of(ingredient);
                Mono<Link> link = linkTo(methodOn(ServiceController.class).getIngredientById(id)).withSelfRel().toMono();
                return link.map(lk -> model.add(lk));
            });
    }
}
```

IngredientServiceClient.getIngredientById

```
    public Mono<Ingredient> getIngredientById(String id) {
        return wcBuilder.build()
                .get().uri("http://ingredient-api/ingredients/{id}", id)
                .retrieve().bodyToMono(Ingredient.class);
    }
```

When I access to `localhost:8082/ingredients/FLTO` a node of my webapp, it shows me only the relative path like this

```
{
  "id": "FLTO",
  "name": "Flour Tortilla",
  "type": "WRAP",
  "_links": {
    "self": {
      "href": "/ingredients/FLTO"
    }
  }
}
```

I've tried the `WebMvcLinkBuilder` but it still did not work correctly. I found [some explanations](https://gitter.im/spring-projects/spring-hateoas?at=5eac7fab5cd4fe50a3e3d568) about my problem. But I'm not sure whether the context/exchange was null (and why). Could you help me?

Answer (score 0):

try to set spring.main.web-application-type=reactive